# 12V to 5V DC-DC converter is outputting 7.5V

Tags: dc-dc-converter

I recently bought [these](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/isolated-dc-dc-converters/1616715/?relevancy-data=636F3D3126696E3D4931384E525353746F636B4E756D626572266C753D656E266D6D3D6D61746368616C6C26706D3D5E2828282872737C5253295B205D3F293F285C647B337D5B5C2D5C735D3F5C647B332C347D5B705061415D3F29297C283235285C647B387D7C5C647B317D5C2D5C647B377D2929292426706F3D3126736E3D592673723D2673743D52535F53544F434B5F4E554D4245522677633D4E4F4E45267573743D3136312D36373135267374613D3136313637313526&searchHistory=%7B%22enabled%22%3Atrue%7D) DC-DC converters. But when I apply 12VDC to the input I always observe 7.5V on the scope instead of 5V, I tried with a 680k load still 7.5V. But the datasheet says this is 12 to 5V converter.

What could be the reason?

[image]

Comment: Which part number do you have? Also post a schematic of how you connect and measure it.

Comment: Connections are correct part no is TMV 1205S. See the answer below somehow if the load is light it cannot regulate.

Comment: @cm64 I am glad the answer is providing what you need, but "Connections are correct" is not a valid response to the request of providing schematics in general. You believe it is correct, but you have a problem. So give the people trying to help you the information they request.

Comment: Max load is 200mA, so hook up something that gives better current. 1k through-hole or so.

Comment: The idle current is ~20mA. Try a 5mA load (1k) although it is supposed to work no load

Comment: @EugeneSh. See the edit

Comment: Your power supply ground isn't connected to anything.

Comment: @Transistor What do you mean?

Comment: Sorry. I was looking on a reduced width display so the image was scaled and the vertical ground line was dropped. When I view the image at 100% scale I can see that the ground *is* connected.

Comment: I work with computer power supplies that output 7v on a regular basis.  Exactly 5vdc would be unusually precise, especially when voltage varies with (among other things) temperature and manufacturing variances.  What are the rated Vmax and Vmin for the converter?  You may be looking at a normal output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using a lower value resistor. With this one you get 11uA of current, which is close to open line. Try getting 10-20mA of load with resistor of say a couple of hundred ohms (200-300 should work) .

Comment: You are right I tried with 560 Ohm load it worked. I need to use So the load should sink min some amount of current? But it doesn't write in datasheet. At what output current do you think it starts to regulate properly?

Comment: It is 5.6V for 560 Ohm

Comment: @cm64 "Input current no load /full load. 5 Vin models 30 mA / 260 mA typ".

Comment: @Lundin This doesn't directly imply the minimum load current. So yeah, I am surprised there is no clear statement of that.

Comment: It's unusual for it not to be quoted in the datasheet, but as a rule of thumb many DC-DCs have a minimum load requirement of 10% of the rated max load current.

Comment: It lists a load regulation variation of 10% for 20 to 100 percent load. So minimum load for regulation is 20%.

Comment: It's a bit crappy though, usually Minimum Load is listed in the electrical characteristics. This one doesn't write it down... Your best bet is to hook up a small potentiometer and a scope, and figure out how big of a shunt you need to use for your output to regulate and be stable at your desired voltage. If your load is light, you may be better off with a simple linear regulator. If your load is heavy, but sporadic, you may want to bootstrap the DC converter's shutdown pin to save some power.

Answer (score 2):

Since you didn't indicate much details in your analysis of your problem, I might be inclined to suggest ESD damage on the input.  Something has attenuated the feedback that so that it overdriving the output.
The design input current is specified for NO LOAD.

Write to info@tracopower-solutions.com and

- 1) request tech support with all the details of your test of output Voltage vs R or I to full load.
- 2) request an RMA for return and FMEA failure report

Was it packaged in an antistatic bag>?

Comment: I received n a plastic tube and a normal plastic bag not anti-static. I bough 10 of them and I tried two of them they have the same behavior. But Im sure I didnt damage myself.

Comment: THen follow the actions I listed after you do a range to full load tests and include your report

Comment: @cm64 If they arrived with no anti-static protection, then anything could have happened in the post.  They could easily be good from the factory and dead on arrival.

Comment: The datasheet lists characteristics under full load. This is normal behavior, all DC-DC converters have a minimum load below which they will be unable to regulate properly or be unstable. This is not a problem with the specific chip, it's just that normally Minimum Load is a clearly listed characteristic in the datasheet, but this datasheet doesn't list it.

Comment: If it is a DCM converter, it should operate fine with no load for which they only specify the input idle current and no mention of output voltage which we have to presume is nominal within tolerances.  So call or write to the OEM..

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist Does DCM type means isolated regulated output? At this page https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/isolated-dc-dc-converters/1616715/ under Product details it writes "Traco 1W SIP Single/Dual Output Unregulated Isolated DC-DC Converter" so it is unregulated type.

Comment: No, yet this descriptor seems contradictory when the spec is Input Voltage Range  10.8 → 13.2 V dc for 5V output.  An open loop would be a fixed ratio duty cycle Buck converter.  I assume your input is stable anyways.  Did you follow my instructions yet? If not , why not?